# Only want text to take up half the page on desktop - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For the text on my banner, I only want it to take up:
- Half the page on desktop
- Half the page on tablet
- Full page on mobile

Reason being is I don't want the text to go over the man's face on desktop or tablet. I have col-lg-7, but I don't think that's right.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="intro-message">
                    <h1>Adobe Exchange</h1><br>
                    <p class="subtitle">Search the most comprehensive online library of video tutorials, code samples to help you quickly learn how to create the web.</p>
                    <p class="intro-divider"></p>
                     <a href="#register" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span>Register for a Free Account</span></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.intro-header -->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
    .intro-header {
    padding-top: 50px; /* If you're making other pages, make sure there is 50px of padding to make sure the navbar doesn't overlap content! */
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background: url(http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/example-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    ...
</div>
```

For extra-small and small screen size devices it will use a full width column, and for medium and large screen size devices it will use a column that fills 8/12 of the space, and offsets it by 2 "units" to center it.

Comment: Basically, I just want to have the text to take up half the screen (so it would be col-6) until for extra-small and small screen size it will use a full width column.

Comment: I set the width to 8 because for larger screens, the .container div already has some side margins, so 6 won't be exacly half of the screen...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure EXACTLY what you're going for here, but I would suggest using `<div class="col-md-7">` or `<div class="col-sm-7">` to fit your device width better.

EDIT:

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/j8gbrsgs/

Bootstrap defaults to 12 column width for xs devices as it is a mobile first framework